# How to Max Open Trades - TradingView

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have a grid code where it open orders at 10 different levels, however I want to set up a max open trade per level, for example max 3 trades at Level1, 3 trades at level 2 (for a max of 6 open trades), etc.

I have coded it using strategy.opentrades but it takes the total open trades, and not the open trades per level... I am not sure how to do it.
Any help or guide can be helpful, thanks

Check the if Short1, if Short2, etc...

```
//@version=5
strategy(title = 'Grid - Short™', 
     overlay = true,
     calc_on_every_tick = true,
     initial_capital = 1000, 
     commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, 
     commission_value = 0.06, 
     pyramiding = 100,
     default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,
     process_orders_on_close = true, 
     close_entries_rule = 'ANY')

//---------------------------------------------------------------

startDate = input.int(title="START DAY DATE",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31, 
          group = '1. DATE RANGE: Select the date range for backtesting',
             tooltip = "Enter the day of start backtesting.")
startMonth = input.int(title="START MONTH",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12, 
          group = '1. DATE RANGE: Select the date range for backtesting',
             tooltip = "Enter the month of start backtesting.")
startYear = input.int(title="START YEAR",
     defval=2018, minval=1800, maxval=2100, 
          group = '1. DATE RANGE: Select the date range for backtesting',
             tooltip = "Enter the year of start backtesting.")

endDate = input.int(title="END DAY DATE",
     defval=30, minval=1, maxval=31, 
          group = '1. DATE RANGE: Select the date range for backtesting',
             tooltip = "Enter the day of end backtesting.")
endMonth = input.int(title="END MONTH",
     defval=12, minval=1, maxval=12, 
          group = '1. DATE RANGE: Select the date range for backtesting',
             tooltip = "Enter the month of end backtesting.")
endYear = input.int(title="END YEAR",
     defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100, 
          group = '1. DATE RANGE: Select the date range for backtesting',
             tooltip = "Enter the year of end backtesting.")

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

//---------------------------------------------------------------

PercentProfit = input.float(defval = 0.50, 
     title = "GRID PERCENT VALUE", 
         group = "2. GRID CUSTOM SETTING",
             tooltip = "This feature refers to the percentage value of each grid. The value you enter here will allow you to create your custom grid.",
                 confirm = true)

LowerLimit = input.price(defval = 0.00, 
     title = 'LOW GRID POSITION',
         group = "2. GRID CUSTOM SETTING", 
             confirm = true,
                 tooltip = "This feature allows you to set the initial price level of your grid. Click on a price level to start.")

feePerTrade = input.float(defval = 0.06, minval = 0.00, maxval = 100,
     title = "FEE PER TRADE", 
         group = "2. GRID CUSTOM SETTING",
             tooltip = "Set the commission cost your broker charges you for each trade.",
                 confirm = true)

MaxTradesOpen = input(1)
//---------------------------------------------------------------

x1 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 1))     / 100
x2 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 2))     / 100
x3 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 3))     / 100
x4 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 4))     / 100
x5 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 5))     / 100
x6 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 6))     / 100
x7 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 7))     / 100
x8 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 8))     / 100
x9 =    (100 + (PercentProfit * 9))     / 100
x10 =   (100 + (PercentProfit * 10))    / 100

UpperLimit = LowerLimit * x10

//---------------------------------------------------------------

Linea_A         = float(LowerLimit * x1)
Linea_B         = float(LowerLimit * x2)
Linea_C         = float(LowerLimit * x3)
Linea_D         = float(LowerLimit * x4)
Linea_50Percent = float(LowerLimit * x5)
Linea_E         = float(LowerLimit * x6)
Linea_F         = float(LowerLimit * x7)
Linea_G         = float(LowerLimit * x8)
Linea_H         = float(LowerLimit * x9)

//---------------------------------------------------------------

Short1   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_A)         and inDateRange
Short2   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_B)         and inDateRange
Short3   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_C)         and inDateRange
Short4   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_D)         and inDateRange
Short5   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_50Percent) and inDateRange
Short6   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_E)         and inDateRange
Short7   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_F)         and inDateRange
Short8   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_G)         and inDateRange
Short9   = ta.crossover(close, Linea_H)         and inDateRange
Short10  = ta.crossover(close, UpperLimit)      and inDateRange

//---------------------------------------------------------------

isExit1     = ta.crossunder(close, LowerLimit)
isExit2     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_A)
isExit3     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_B)
isExit4     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_C)
isExit5     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_D)
isExit6     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_50Percent)
isExit7     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_E)
isExit8     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_F)
isExit9     = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_G)
isExit10    = ta.crossunder(close, Linea_H)

//---------------------------------------------------------------

plot(LowerLimit,        color =  color.purple,  linewidth = 2)
plot(UpperLimit,        color =  color.purple,  linewidth = 2)

plot(Linea_A,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_B,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_C,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_D,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_50Percent,   color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_E,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_F,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_G,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)
plot(Linea_H,           color =  color.blue,  linewidth = 1)

//---------------------------------------------------------------

fill(plot(LowerLimit), 
     plot(Linea_A), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 90))
fill(plot(Linea_A), 
     plot(Linea_B), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 85))
fill(plot(Linea_B), 
     plot(Linea_C), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 80))
fill(plot(Linea_C), 
     plot(Linea_D), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 70))
fill(plot(Linea_D), 
     plot(Linea_50Percent), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 60))
fill(plot(Linea_50Percent), 
     plot(Linea_E), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 60))
fill(plot(Linea_E), 
     plot(Linea_F), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 70))
fill(plot(Linea_F), 
     plot(Linea_G), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 80))
fill(plot(Linea_G), 
     plot(Linea_H), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 85))
fill(plot(Linea_H), 
     plot(LowerLimit), 
         color = color.new(color.purple, 90))

//---------------------------------------------------------------

if Short1 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT1",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit1 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT1",
         from_entry = "SHORT1", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = LowerLimit,
                 profit = LowerLimit)

if Short2 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT2",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit2 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT2",
         from_entry = "SHORT2", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_A,
                 limit = Linea_A)

if Short3 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT3",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit3 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT3",
         from_entry = "SHORT3", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_B,
                 limit = Linea_B)

if Short4 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT4",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit4 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT4",
         from_entry = "SHORT4", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_C,
                 limit = Linea_C)

if Short5 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen 
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT5",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit5 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT5",
         from_entry = "SHORT5", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_D,
                 limit = Linea_D)

if Short6 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen 
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT6",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit6 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT6",
         from_entry = "SHORT6", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_50Percent,
                 limit = Linea_50Percent)

if Short7 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen 
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT7",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit7 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT7",
         from_entry = "SHORT7", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop  = Linea_E,
                 limit = Linea_E)

if Short8 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen 
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT8",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit8 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT8",
         from_entry = "SHORT8", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_F,
                 limit = Linea_F)

if Short9 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT9",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit9 
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT9",
         from_entry = "SHORT9", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_G,
                 limit = Linea_G)

if Short10 and strategy.opentrades <MaxTradesOpen 
    strategy.entry(id = "SHORT10",  
         direction = strategy.short, 
                 qty = 0.1)
if isExit10
    strategy.exit(id = "EXIT10",
         from_entry = "SHORT10", 
             qty = 100, 
                 stop = Linea_H,
                 limit = Linea_H)
    
//---------------------------------------------------------------

trades          = int(strategy.closedtrades)
initialCapital  = float(strategy.initial_capital)
grossReturn     = trades * PercentProfit
gainCapital     = (initialCapital * grossReturn) / 100
totalCapital    = initialCapital + gainCapital
feeCost         = (totalCapital * feePerTrade) / 100 
totalFeeCost    = feeCost * trades
netCapital      = totalCapital - totalFeeCost - initialCapital

//---------------------------------------------------------------

i_position = input.string(defval = "Bottom Right", 
     title = "Table Placement", 
         options = ["Top Right", "Middle Right", "Bottom Right"], 
             group = "3. Table Characteristics")

position = i_position == "Top Right" ? position.top_right : i_position == "Middle Right" ? position.middle_right : position.bottom_right

i_w = input.int(title = "Width", 
     defval = 14, 
         group = "3. Table Characteristics")
i_h = input.int(title = "Height", 
     defval = 8, 
         group = "3. Table Characteristics")
i_text_size = input(title = "Text Size", 
     defval = "Normal")

text_size = i_text_size == "Normal" ? size.normal : i_text_size == "Auto" ? size.auto : i_text_size == "Auto" ? size.auto : i_text_size == "Tiny" ? size.tiny
  : i_text_size == "Small" ? size.small : i_text_size == "Large" ? size.large : size.huge

i   = input.bool(title = "1. Capital", 
     defval = true, 
         group = "4. Enable Rows",
             tooltip = "Initial capital of the strategy.")

i_1 = input.bool(title = "2. Gross Returns", 
     defval = true, 
         group = "4. Enable Rows",
             tooltip = "Total strategy return. Contains the initial capital plus the sum of the gains.")

i_2 = input.bool(title = "3. Gain Percent", 
     defval = true, 
         group = "4. Enable Rows",
             tooltip = "Percentage return of strategy gains.")

i_3 = input.bool(title = "4. Commission Cost", 
     defval = true, 
         group = "4. Enable Rows",
             tooltip = "Percentage return of strategy gains.")

i_4 = input.bool(title = "5. Net Returns", 
     defval = true, 
         group = "4. Enable Rows",
             tooltip = "Total commission cost.")

i_5 = input.bool(title = "6. Closed Trades",
     defval = true, 
         group = "4. Enable Rows",
             tooltip = "Total trades.")


var table perfTable = table.new(position, 2, 11, frame_color = color.purple, frame_width = 1, border_width = 1)

//---------------------------------------------------------------

if i
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, 0, "1.  GROSS RETURN", 
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size,
                             text_halign = text.align_left)
if i
    table.cell(perfTable, 1, 0, 
         text = str.tostring(totalCapital) + " $", 
             bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
                 text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                     width = i_w, 
                         height = i_h, 
                             text_size = text_size)

if i_1
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, 1,  "2.  INITIAL CAPITAL", 
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90),  
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size,
                             text_halign = text.align_left)
if i_1
    table.cell(perfTable, 1, 1, text = str.tostring(initialCapital) + " $", 
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90),  
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size)

if i_2
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, 2, "3.  GAIN",  
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size,
                             text_halign = text.align_left)
if i_2
    table.cell(perfTable, 1, 2, 
         text = str.tostring(grossReturn) + " %", 
             bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
                 text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                     width = i_w, 
                         height = i_h, 
                             text_size = text_size)

if i_3
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, 3, "4.  FEE COST", 
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size,
                             text_halign = text.align_left)
if i_3
    table.cell(perfTable, 1, 3, 
         text = str.tostring(totalFeeCost) + " $", 
             bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
                 text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                     width = i_w, 
                         height = i_h, 
                             text_size = text_size)

if i_4
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, 4, "5. NET RETURN", 
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size,
                             text_halign = text.align_left)
if i_4
    table.cell(perfTable, 1, 4, 
         text = str.tostring(netCapital) + " $",  
             bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90), 
                 text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                     width = i_w, 
                         height = i_h, 
                             text_size = text_size)

if i_5
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, 6,  "6. CLOSED TRADES", 
         bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90),  
             text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                 width = i_w, 
                     height = i_h, 
                         text_size = text_size,
                                 text_halign = text.align_left)
if i_5
    table.cell(perfTable, 1, 6,  
         text = str.tostring(trades), 
             bgcolor = color.new(color.purple, 90),  
                 text_color = color.new(color.black, 0), 
                     width = i_w, 
                         height = i_h, 
                             text_size = text_size)

//---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an integer counter per level

```
var int count1 = 0
var int count2 = 0
....
```

And incrementing the relevant counter whenever a specific level is hit

```
if level_1_hit
    count1 += 1
if level_2_hit
    count2 += 1

// Enter 3 trades at level 1 maximum
if level_1_hit and count1 < 3
    strategy.entry(...)
```